# Angular-Chart and creating multiple charts on one page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, angular-chart

Looking for some help with including multiple angular-chart objects on a single page. I would like to create a dashboard like page that includes multiple charts. I have my charts working and they are pulling from a MySQL back, but I can never get more than one chart to load at a time. I can add several charts and the first one will load, but none that follow it. I can comment out the first chart and the next one will load. Individually, all charts will load fine, just not in any combination of other charts. I have tried using different chart types, different angular applications, different controllers, etc. Currently, I have two charts wired up to call two different PHP files that are a copy of one another. The second php chart never gets called in the stack trace. Coded the most simply:

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-4" id="Chart1">
            <div ng-controller="PieCtrl" ng-app="ChartApp">
        <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels"></canvas>
    </div> 

    <script>angular.module('ChartApp', ['chart.js']);</script>
    <script>
        angular.module("ChartApp", ["chart.js"]).controller("PieCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('./GetTestData.php').success(function(data) {
    var names = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = data[i];

        if (obj.Name != undefined) {
            names.push(obj.Name);
        }
    }

    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = data[i];

        if (obj.Name != undefined) {
            values.push(obj.Value);
        }
    }
    //$scope.records = data;
    $scope.labels = names;
    $scope.data = values;
});

});
    </script>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4" id="Chart2">
            <p>Test2</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div ng-controller="PieCtrl2" ng-app="ChartApp2">
        <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" chart-data="data1" chart-labels="labels1"></canvas>
    </div> 

    <script>angular.module('ChartApp2', ['chart.js']);</script>
    <script>
        angular.module("ChartApp2", ["chart.js"]).controller("PieCtrl2", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('./GetTestData2.php').success(function(data) {
    var names = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = data[i];

        if (obj.Name != undefined) {
            names.push(obj.Name);
        }
    }

    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = data[i];

        if (obj.Name != undefined) {
            values.push(obj.Value);
        }
    }
    //$scope.records = data;
    $scope.labels1 = names;
    $scope.data1 = values;
});

});
    </script>
```

Comment: try using the same module: angular.module("ChartApp", ["chart.js"]) and no "ChartApp2". I have multiple chart on the same page and it work fine